# Pagination feature in Vonage template listing API

Tags: vonage

I came across the whatsapp template listing API(https://developer.vonage.com/en/api/whatsapp-template-management#ListTemplates) provided by vonage and couldn't understand the relevance of the pageination query param values "before" and "after".

It would be helpfull if someone could let me know how these values are generated at the first place.